# Analytical solution for binomial equation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Suppose that the random variable $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}_{n,p}$, and suppose we have $p' \in [0,1]$.  I have been asked to solve for the least $n$ such that $P(X \leq 2) = p'$.

It was completely straight-forward to write:

$$
p' = \binom{n}{0} q^n p^0 + \binom{n}{1} q^{n-1}p^1 + \binom{n}{2} q^{n-2}{p^2} \\
   = q^n + nq^{n-1}p + \binom{n}{2} q^{n-2}p^2
$$

However, I don't know (or at least remember) any analytical techniques to actually solve for $n$.  Is it possible?  I would be extremely happy with a hint! :)

Come to think of it, using a normal approximation, while not *a priori* good, could work if $n$ was large enough.  (In the particular problem I'm working on, it turns out that $n$ *is* large enough, but I didn't know that until I brute-forced the solution).  Is there a good test to check whether $n$ is large enough for the normal approximation here?

Comment: You have the roles of $p$ and $q$ switched.

Comment: Oops, good point, thanks!